# A chat -theme for the MathOverflow chat

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design, chat

The [MathOverflow chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9369/mathoverflow) needs a chat-theme (in my opinion), because the current one doesn't look very beautiful.
It should fit with the design of the main. Does someone have a design in mind, or wants to work on one?

**Added** (by quid, in view of an answer): the current (september 12th, 2013) theme is already the MO-theme.

Comment: This is absolutely planned; every site gets its own chat theme that fits the main site. We just didn't have time to do it before the move, so for now it's the default Stack Exchange skin, but you'll get your own within the next few days.

Answer (score 1):

No, there should not be one.  [Science Fiction and Fantasy stackexchange](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/) has a chat style with a starred sky pattern in the background.  The stars show up even as the background of chatter text.  I don't like text on a non-uniform background, and believe it should appear only in tabloid newspapers.  I hope I'm not the only typographical purist among mathematicians here.

Comment: Just because the theme of some other chat does not look nice does not mean the chat should not have a theme. Does it even make sense to not have a theme? I mean, any graphical style it does have will be the theme.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: yes, we could have a theme, but the currently used theme looks fine to me.

Comment: And indeed, it is the theme meant for MO (note that the question is fairly old and tagged with status-completed).

Comment: Ah, I see. It would be nice if you could add that to the question itself, not only the tags.

Comment: I added a sentence to the question.